# jhipster error while running

Tags: node.js, maven, jhipster

i did npm install -g yo 
and npm install -g generator-jhipster  for installing yoeman and jhipster and then i created a project by running "yo jhipster" answered all questions and then when i doing 
mvn -Pprod spring-boot:run 
it gives me error 
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.trecloux:yeoman-maven-plugin:0.2:build (run-grunt) on project myproject: Error during : grunt test --no-color: Process exited with an error: 6 (Exit value: 6) -> [Help 1]

can somebody help me into i am kind of new into this.

Comment: You have an error in your JavaScript test, the "grunt test" task is failing -> can you run it and look at the output?

Comment: grunt test                               
                                                              Running "clean:server" (clean) task
Cleaning .tmp...OK

Running "concurrent:test" (concurrent) task
    Warning: Running "compass:dist" (compass) task
    Warning: You need to have Ruby and Compass installed and in your system PATH for this task to work. More info: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass Use --force to continue.
    
    Aborted due to warnings.

Answer (score 1):

From reading your comments:

- You have selected the "Compass" option. This is not the default option, and your error comes from this option, not from MongoDB (the title of your question is misleading)
- As the message tells you: if you want to use Compass, you need to install Compass.

So either install Compass, or choose the option not to use it.